# Recursive iteration in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a custom object that contains methods that returns all directory and file names in a root

```
string[] dirlist = obj.GetDirectories();

//which returns all dir names in root

string[] filelist = obj.GetFiles();

//which return all file names in root
```

I cannot modify these methods. Once I get the dirlist, how do i get a list of all subdirs in it as well as files in the subdirs, ignoring the security exceptions. It can be nested to multiple levels. Anything in .NET 4?

Update: string[] dirList can also be read as List dirlist. Please give a solution that uses the latest features of .NET

```
DirectoryOne  
 - SubDirOne  
 - SubDirTwo  
     - FileOne  
     - FileTwo
     - SubDirThree      
DirectoryTwo
DirectoryOne
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the result you want to achieve?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you want, do you just want to recursively get all folders and files?

Comment: yes once i get the dirlist, I want to loop through each dir and get a list of nested subdirs and finally file in that subdir

Comment: @lea do `dirlist` and `filelist` return ALL folders and files including in sub folders of the root? Do they both return the full path?

Comment: no that's the issue..dirlist just returns the directory names. Somehow i have to get the subdirs from these names

Comment: To skip security exceptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393178/unauthorizedaccessexception-cannot-resolve-directory-getfiles-failure

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are already built-in .NET methods to do this:

```
// get all files in folder and sub-folders
Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

// get all sub-directories
Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Somehow I get the feeling this isn't the solution you're looking for though.

**Update:**
I think I may know what you're trying to ask, since you tagged it as LINQ. If you want to get a list of all sub-directories and sub-folders given a list of directories, you can use the following code:

```
// get all files given a collection of directories as a string array
dirList.SelectMany(x => Directory.GetFiles(x, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));

// get all sub-directories given a collection of directories as a string array
dirList.SelectMany(x => x.Directory.GetDirectories(x, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
```

Comment: yes what do I give in the path..that's the issue. Actually the API they have given me is pretty screwed up.

Comment: Whoops, changed `dirList.Select` to `dirList.SelectMany`.

Comment: will this code also get directories inside subdirs? I mean it can nested to any level. So for eg: a subdir may contain some files and some more dirs which may contains files and dirs and so on. I want to list them all.

Comment: Yes, it will recursively go down and get all files/directories from all sub-directories, no matter how deep.

Comment: ok thanks one last ques..i have updated the question to show a preview of the output i wanted. How can i get the output..should i store the result in a list or print on console. Any ideas how to do either of them

Comment: Unfortunately, getting a list of all the files in a directory and building out a tree like that are two different issues. Try looking up some other SO questions, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005551/construct-a-tree-structure-from-list-of-string-paths

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Directory Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx)

```
foreach(string dir in Directory.GetDirectories("c:\","",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
 Console.Writeline(dir);
 foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
 {
   Console.Writline(file);
 } 
}
```

This will print all directories under `C:\` and then all the files in each of those directories.
Does that help?