# Working with nested dictionaries and formatting for display

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a partial answer from here [Construct a tree from list os file paths (Python) - Performance dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484943/construct-a-tree-from-list-os-file-paths-python-performance-dependent)
My specific problem requires me to go from

this

```
dir/file  10  
dir/dir2/file2  20  
dir/dir2/file3  10
dir/file3  10  
dir3/file4  10  
dir3/file5  10
```

To

```
dir/  **50**     
    dir2/  **30**    
        file2  
        file3
    file
    file3  
dir3/  **20**  
    file4  
    file5
```

Basically the numbers at the end are the file sizes and
I have been trying to figure out how to display the size of all the files to the parent directory

Edit:

```
r = re.compile(r'(.+\t)(\d+)')
    def prettify(d, indent=0):
        for key, value in d.iteritems():
            ss = 0
            if key == FILE_MARKER:
                if value:
                    for each in value:
                        mm = r.match(each)
                        ss +=  int(mm.group(2))
                        print '  ' * indent + each
                        ***print '    ' * indent  + format_size(ss)***
            else:
                print '  ' * indent + str(key)
                if isinstance(value, dict):
                    addSizes(value, indent+1)
                else:
                    print '  ' * (indent+1) + str(value)
```

This is mac's answer from the above link which i edited to use regExp
Solutions that occurred to me led me to create a new dict or adding an inner  function.
I have lost my whole day and wished i had asked for help earlier in the day.
Please help.

Comment: @larsks I am able to add up the sizes and display it after the list of files after each dir but stuck with displaying it on the dir/ line.

Comment: You should show us what you have tried then we can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most elegant thing in the world, but this should get you where you need to be. You'll need to change the tree creation function to deal with whatever form of input you are getting. Once the tree is generated it's just using a recursive tree traversal to form the output.

```
import re
input_dirs = """dir/file  10  
dir/dir2/file2  20  
dir/dir2/file3  10
dir/file  10  
dir3/file4  10  
dir3/file5  10
dir/dir2/dir4/file2 10"""

def create_file_tree(input_string):
    dir_dict = {}
    for file_path in input_string.split('\n'):
        path_list = re.sub('/',' ',file_path).split()
        path_list[-1] = int(path_list[-1])
        path_dict = dir_dict
        final_item = ""
        for item in path_list[:-1]:
            parent_dict = path_dict
            last_item = item
            path_dict = path_dict.setdefault(item,{})
        parent_dict[last_item] = path_list[-1]
    return dir_dict

def pretty_file_tree(file_tree):
    def traverse(sub_dict,indent=0, total=0):
        string_out = ""
        indent += 1
        for key in sorted(sub_dict.keys()):
            if type(sub_dict[key]) == dict:
                sub_total = traverse(sub_dict[key],indent,0)
                total += sub_total[0]
                string_out += '  '*indent + key + ' ' + '**' + str(sub_total[0]) + '**' + '\n' + sub_total[1]
            else:
                string_out += '  '*indent + key  + '\n'
                total += sub_dict[key]

        return total, string_out

    output_string = traverse(file_tree)
    print(output_string[1])

pretty_file_tree(create_file_tree(input_dirs))
```

Sorry it's not following the code you posted, but i'd begun to produce this before the edit...

Comment: elegant or not it works like a million bucks right now.so thanks a lot.I have tested it on a single file right now.I have to run this against a huge number of text file spread across Multiple folders.

Answer (score 0):

As you process the input build a string with place holders (%d) for the numbers, then print out the string.