# Java Tree to represent filesystem (files/dir) from list of paths

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, filesystems

I've a list of paths like this

```
/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file1
/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file2
/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file3
/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file4
/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file5
/mnt/sdcard/folder1/e/c/file6
/mnt/sdcard/folder2/d/file7
/mnt/sdcard/folder2/d/file8
/mnt/sdcard/file9
```

So from this list of paths (Stings) I need to crete a Java Tree structure that has folders as nodes and files as leaf (there wont be empty folders as leaf).

What I need I think is the add method where I pass to them a String (path of the file) and it add it to the correct place in the tree creating correct nodes (Folder) if they are not already there

This tree structure will need me to get list of nodes when I'm on node and list of leafs (but I think this will be a normal features for trees)

I will always have Strings as paths and not real file or folders.
Is there something ready to use or a source code to start?

Thank you very much.

Comment: *"source code to start?"*  See [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui).

Comment: **See also:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005551/construct-a-tree-structure-from-list-of-string-paths

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thank you for all your answer. I made my working implementation.
I think that I will need to improve it in order to make it works better with more caching in adding element to the tree structure.

As I said what I was needing was a structure that allow me to have a "virtual" rappresentation of a FS.

MXMTree.java

```
public class MXMTree {

    MXMNode root;
    MXMNode commonRoot;

    public MXMTree( MXMNode root ) {
        this.root = root;
        commonRoot = null;
    }

    public void addElement( String elementValue ) { 
        String[] list = elementValue.split("/");

        // latest element of the list is the filename.extrension
        root.addElement(root.incrementalPath, list);

    }

    public void printTree() {
        //I move the tree common root to the current common root because I don't mind about initial folder
        //that has only 1 child (and no leaf)
        getCommonRoot();
        commonRoot.printNode(0);
    }

    public MXMNode getCommonRoot() {
        if ( commonRoot != null)
            return commonRoot;
        else {
            MXMNode current = root;
            while ( current.leafs.size() <= 0 ) {
                current = current.childs.get(0);
            }
            commonRoot = current;
            return commonRoot;
        }

    }


}
```

MXMNode.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class MXMNode {

    List<MXMNode> childs;
    List<MXMNode> leafs;
    String data;
    String incrementalPath;

    public MXMNode( String nodeValue, String incrementalPath ) {
        childs = new ArrayList<MXMNode>();
        leafs = new ArrayList<MXMNode>();
        data = nodeValue;
        this. incrementalPath = incrementalPath;
    }

    public boolean isLeaf() {
        return childs.isEmpty() && leafs.isEmpty();
    }

    public void addElement(String currentPath, String[] list) {

        //Avoid first element that can be an empty string if you split a string that has a starting slash as /sd/card/
        while( list[0] == null || list[0].equals("") )
            list = Arrays.copyOfRange(list, 1, list.length);

        MXMNode currentChild = new MXMNode(list[0], currentPath+"/"+list[0]);
        if ( list.length == 1 ) {
            leafs.add( currentChild );
            return;
        } else {
            int index = childs.indexOf( currentChild );
            if ( index == -1 ) {
                childs.add( currentChild );
                currentChild.addElement(currentChild.incrementalPath, Arrays.copyOfRange(list, 1, list.length));
            } else {
                MXMNode nextChild = childs.get(index);
                nextChild.addElement(currentChild.incrementalPath, Arrays.copyOfRange(list, 1, list.length));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        MXMNode cmpObj = (MXMNode)obj;
        return incrementalPath.equals( cmpObj.incrementalPath ) && data.equals( cmpObj.data );
    }

    public void printNode( int increment ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < increment; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(incrementalPath + (isLeaf() ? " -> " + data : "")  );
        for( MXMNode n: childs)
            n.printNode(increment+2);
        for( MXMNode n: leafs)
            n.printNode(increment+2);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data;
    }


}
```

Test.java for test code

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String slist[] = new String[] { 
                "/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file1.file", 
                "/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file2.file", 
                "/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file3.file", 
                "/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file4.file",
                "/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file5.file", 
                "/mnt/sdcard/folder1/e/c/file6.file", 
                "/mnt/sdcard/folder2/d/file7.file", 
                "/mnt/sdcard/folder2/d/file8.file", 
                "/mnt/sdcard/file9.file" 
        };

        MXMTree tree = new MXMTree(new MXMNode("root", "root"));
        for (String data : slist) {
            tree.addElement(data);
        }

        tree.printTree();
    }

}
```

Please tell me if you have some good advice about improvments :)

Comment: I think a good way to improve it would be to add an easy way to traverse the tree. Other than that, good job

Answer (score 3):

I implemented a solution to the challenge myself, it is [available as a GitHubGist](https://gist.github.com/SchulteMarkus/1a67f4e6081d0f2f4e0481bf967fd17f).

I am representing each node of a filesystem-hierarchy in a DirectoryNode. A helper-method *createDirectoryTree(String[] filesystemList)* creates a direcotry-tree.

Here is the usage example, which is included in the [GitHubGist](https://gist.github.com/SchulteMarkus/1a67f4e6081d0f2f4e0481bf967fd17f).

```
final String[] list = new String[]{
  "/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file1.file",
  "/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file2.file",
  "/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file3.file",
  "/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file4.file",
  "/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file5.file",
  "/mnt/sdcard/folder1/e/c/file6.file",
  "/mnt/sdcard/folder2/d/file7.file",
  "/mnt/sdcard/folder2/d/file8.file",
  "/mnt/sdcard/file9.file"
};

final DirectoryNode directoryRootNode = createDirectoryTree(list);

System.out.println(directoryRootNode);
```

The *System.out.println* -output is:

```
  {value='mnt', children=[{value='sdcard', children=[{value='folder1', 
  children=[{value='a', children=[{value='b', children=[{value='file1.file', 
  children=[]}, {value='file2.file', children=[]}, {value='file3.file', 
  children=[]}, {value='file4.file', children=[]}, {value='file5.file', 
  children=[]}]}]}, {value='e', children=[{value='c', 
  children=[{value='file6.file', children=[]}]}]}]}, 
  {value='folder2', children=[{value='d', children=[{value='file7.file', 
  children=[]}, {value='file8.file', children=[]}]}]}, 
  {value='file9.file', children=[]}]}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you could adapt either a [Trie](http://code.google.com/p/java-algorithms-implementation/source/browse/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/data_structures/Trie.java) / [Radix Trie](http://code.google.com/p/java-algorithms-implementation/source/browse/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/data_structures/RadixTrie.java) or a [Binary Search Tree](http://code.google.com/p/java-algorithms-implementation/source/browse/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/data_structures/BinarySearchTree.java) to work in either situation. You could augment a Trie to store "folders" as the inner nodes (instead of characters like in a regular Trie) or you could augment a Binary Search Tree to store "folders" as inner nodes (as long as they implement a comparable interface) and "files" as leaf nodes.

My implementation of those structures are linked in the text above.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading up on [data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure), particularly [trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29). In Java, you can represent these by creating a node class that has references to other nodes. For example:

```
public class Node {
    private Node[] children;
    /* snip other fields */
    public boolean isFile() {
         return children.count == 0;
    }
}
```

Obviously, you can store your node references anyway you like- arrays or collections will work with non-binary trees.

Given your list of files, you can read these and populate your tree structure.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look in new [Java 7 - nio2 package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html). All you need is inside.

Comment: This is useful but doesn't take a a list of text paths as input, which is fine if you literally want to navigate an actual file system. But in my case I want  to cache my virtual file system (abstracting a database) in a txt file.