# Creating dynamic JTree from absolute file path

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtree

```
private void createNodes(DefaultMutableTreeNode top) {
    List <String> files = new ArrayList<String>();      
    //getFileNames() returns array list of file name with complete path
    //eg C:/lanceTest1/directory1/sample.txt
    files = getFileNames();     
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = null;
    for (String fileName : files) {
        node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(fileName);
        top.add(node);               
    }
}
```

Above function creates below window.

[image]

I want to show it as below (for eg for the first file),

```
The Java Series
 |__C
  |__lanceTest
   |__directory1
    |__PDxxxx_Splunk_Solution_Architecture_Doc_v0.9.doc
```

I am new to swing, awt. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help. Basically I wanted to represent file system from the path which i retrieve from database. Files/directories are not actually stored on database but are dynamically generated from absolute/relative path.

I found answer here...

[Java Tree to represent filesystem (files/dir) from list of paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929775/java-tree-to-represent-filesystem-files-dir-from-list-of-paths)

Answer (score 5):

- please read Oracle tutorial [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)
- [examples about described methods, listeners, rest of methods](https://java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Catalog0240__Swing.htm)
- for example

[image][image]

from code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;

public class FileTree extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public FileTree(File dir) {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTree tree = new JTree(addNodes(null, dir));
        tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.getPath().getLastPathComponent();
                System.out.println("You selected " + node);
            }
        });
        DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultTreeCellRenderer) tree.getCellRenderer();
        renderer.setLeafIcon(null);
        renderer.setClosedIcon(null);
        renderer.setOpenIcon(null);
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollpane.getViewport().add(tree);
        add(BorderLayout.CENTER, scrollpane);
    }

    private DefaultMutableTreeNode addNodes(DefaultMutableTreeNode curTop, File dir) {
        String curPath = dir.getPath();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode curDir = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(curPath);
        if (curTop != null) {
            curTop.add(curDir);
        }
        Vector<String> ol = new Vector<String>();
        String[] tmp = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
            ol.addElement(tmp[i]);
        }
        Collections.sort(ol, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        File f;
        Vector<Object> files = new Vector<Object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ol.size(); i++) {
            String thisObject = ol.elementAt(i);
            String newPath;
            if (curPath.equals(".")) {
                newPath = thisObject;
            } else {
                newPath = curPath + File.separator + thisObject;
            }
            if ((f = new File(newPath)).isDirectory()) {
                addNodes(curDir, f);
            } else {
                files.addElement(thisObject);
            }
        }
        for (int fnum = 0; fnum < files.size(); fnum++) {
            curDir.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(files.elementAt(fnum)));
        }
        return curDir;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 400);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 400);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] av) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("FileTree");
                frame.setForeground(Color.black);
                frame.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                Container cp = frame.getContentPane();
                if (av.length == 0) {
                    cp.add(new FileTree(new File(".")));
                } else {
                    cp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cp, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
                    for (int i = 0; i < av.length; i++) {
                        cp.add(new FileTree(new File(av[i])));
                    }
                }
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: side question, why does your avatar change between 2 different images? (or even how is it done?)

Comment: @Reimeus my avatar corresponding with PCs IP Addres (blue is office, green is home, and various avatars are attached when I logged from my brick - cellphone, then IP is added dynamically by carrier)

Answer (score 2):

See also the [File Browser GUI](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui).

[image]