# Transfer file path from file tree to another class

Tags: java, swing, jtree

This may be a bit confusing to explain but I will try my best. I have a class called FileBrowser and there is a line which is `String hello=fileNode.getFile` that takes the clicked file node from the Jtree and saves it to the variable hello. Full class is below.

FileBrowser.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class FileBrowser extends JPanel {

    public DefaultMutableTreeNode root;

    public DefaultTreeModel treeModel;

    public JTree tree;


    public FileBrowser() {
        //JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Browser");
        //frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        File fileRoot = new File("C://");
        root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new FileNode(fileRoot));
        treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);

        tree = new JTree(treeModel);

        tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);

        tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent event) {
                /* new */
                DefaultMutableTreeNode dmtn = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)
                        tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
                FileNode fileNode = (FileNode)dmtn.getUserObject();
                File file = fileNode.getFile();

               //THIS THE STRING I WOULD LIKE TO TRANSFER TO VIEWER_NAVIGATOR
               String hello=file.toString();



                call(hello,dmtn);

            }
        });


       // frame.add(scrollPane);
        //frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        //frame.setSize(640, 480);
        //frame.setVisible(true);

        CreateChildNodes ccn = 
                new CreateChildNodes(fileRoot, root);
        new Thread(ccn).start();
    }


    private void call(String file, DefaultMutableTreeNode dmtn) {
        System.out.println("Exporting file and converting to HTML");
         String[] arguments = new String[] {file, dmtn+".html", "HTML"};
     OITSample.func(arguments);     
    }






    public class CreateChildNodes implements Runnable {

        private DefaultMutableTreeNode root;

        private File fileRoot;

        public CreateChildNodes(File fileRoot, 
                DefaultMutableTreeNode root) {
            this.fileRoot = fileRoot;
            this.root = root;
        }

        public void run() {
            createChildren(fileRoot, root);
        }

        private void createChildren(File fileRoot, 
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
            File[] files = fileRoot.listFiles();
            if (files == null) return;

            for (File file : files) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = 
                        new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new FileNode(file));
                node.add(childNode);
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    createChildren(file, childNode);
                }}}}

    public class FileNode {

        private File file;

        public FileNode(File file) {
            this.file = file;
        }

        public File getFile() {
            return file;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String name = file.getName();
            if (name.equals("")) {
                return file.getAbsolutePath();
            } else {
                return name;
            }}}}
```

I would like to take the String variable,hello, and when a file node is clicked, the variable gets sent to the Viewer_Navigator class below, to the area which takes a file at the editorpane. This is area specifically:

```
           File file = new File("the string hello from the other class should go in here");
```

Viewer_Navigator.java

```
public class Viewer_Navigator {


    private JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String defStartParams = "AdminStart.xml";

        String adminParams = parseXML(defStartParams);

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Viewer_Navigator window = new Viewer_Navigator();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private static String parseXML(String defStartParams) {
        // We're cheating for now
        String params = "sb_ContName='com.staorbase.service.SB_AdminSvc'";
        params += ";";

        return params;
    }

    /**
    * Create the application.
    */
    public Viewer_Navigator() {



        initialize();
    }

    /**
    * Initialize the contents of the frame.
    */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 840, 545);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  //put the jframe on center of the screen -added


        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        frame.getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        final JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(0.8);
        splitPane.setResizeWeight(0.3);
        frame.getContentPane().add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        FileBrowser testing=new FileBrowser();


        final JEditorPane editorpane= new JEditorPane();
           final JScrollPane editorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorpane);
           editorScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        final JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panel2.add(editorScrollPane);
           File file = new File("the string 'hello' from the other class should go in here");
           try {
            editorpane.setPage(file.toURI().toURL());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


            JScrollPane jScrollPane=new JScrollPane();

            jScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            jScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            jScrollPane.setViewportBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));
            jScrollPane.getViewport().add(testing.tree);


            final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panel.add(jScrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);


         splitPane.setLeftComponent(panel);
        splitPane.setRightComponent(panel2);
    }



}
```

Any suggestions on how I should go about doing this? Please let me know if you need any clarifications.

Thank you

Comment: You display folders and files in a `JTree` and you want to open a window to allow editing the file that the user clicks on in the tree, correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. I just need to get the clicked file from the FileBrowser into the editorPane and I believe I know how to do the rest.

Comment: In method `valueChanged()` in class `FileBrowser`, simply open a custom `JDialog` that contains some _Swing_ component through which you can display and edit the contents of the file, like `JTextArea`. Note that you will need to write a class that extends `JDialog`. Perhaps simply convert your `Viewer_Navigator` class. If you would like me to provide you with actual code for how to achieve this, just let me know.

Comment: In my case I have to do it so that it displays the content in the splitPane in the Viewer_Navigator class, specifically the right component. I would not be allowed to do it any other way unfortunately.

Comment: An excerpt from Oracle's [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html): _Swing provides three generally useful top-level container classes: `JFrame`, `JDialog`, and `JApplet`_ In other words, what you can do with a `JFrame`, you can also do with a `JDialog` and a _Swing_ application should consist of precisely one `JFrame`.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Do you think you could show me the code to achieve this? That would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Display file(s) name and select it under the folder in JTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224096/display-files-name-and-select-it-under-the-folder-in-jtree) , [List files and directories with Jtree and File in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804675/list-files-and-directories-with-jtree-and-file-in-java/25511740) , [Creating dynamic JTree from absolute file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112119/creating-dynamic-jtree-from-absolute-file-path)