# I want to display the absolute filepaths on jsp as a tree structure.....how can I achieve this

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am creating a spring web app for comparing two directories and I had stored all the absolute path of the directories containing file in a ArrayList now I want to display them on the jsp page as a tree structure but I am not getting how to implement this so please can anybody help me solving this.......how can I display the paths contained in the arraylist as a tree structure on JSP.....

I am trying to print like this.....

```
Root


|
|----Dependencies
|        |----A
 |        |----B
 |        |----C
 |
|----Dependents
      |----D
      |----E
```

This is my code for controller.... from which I am sending the list of path to jsp using session variable....my absolute paths are contained in the list **filepath_firstdir**  and I want this filepath_firstdir to be printed on jsp as a tree.........

```
@Controller
public class DirectorySearchController {

public File folder;
public File folder2;
public Map<String,String> filepath_firstdir = new HashMap<String,String>();
public Map<String,String> filepath_seconddir = new HashMap<String,String>();
public List<String> filepath=new ArrayList<String>();
public Map<String,List<String>> NoChange=new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
public Map<String,List<String>> change=new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
public Map<String, String> newfile=new HashMap<String, String>();
public StringBuffer hex;
public StringBuffer hex1;
public HttpSession session;
public String msg;

@RequestMapping("/directory")
public ModelAndView scanDirectory(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException
{
     String first_path=request.getParameter("uploaddir1");
     String second_path=request.getParameter("uploaddir2");

     folder = new File(first_path);
     folder2=new File(second_path);
     filepath_firstdir=listFilesForFolder(folder);

     filepath_seconddir=listFilesForFolder(folder2);


     /*String s=filepath_firstdir.toString();
     String[] tokens=s.split("####");
     for(String token:tokens)
         filepath_seconddir.add(token);*/

     session=request.getSession();
     session.setAttribute("filepath_firstdir", filepath_firstdir);
     session.setAttribute("filepath_seconddir", filepath_seconddir);

     System.out.println(filepath_firstdir);
     System.out.println(filepath_seconddir);

     Iterator itr=filepath_firstdir.entrySet().iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            Entry entry=(Entry) itr.next();
            Object key=entry.getKey();
            Object value=entry.getValue();
            if(filepath_seconddir.containsValue(value))
            {
                hex=MD5Encryption.convertToHashCode(key.toString());
                Iterator itr2=filepath_seconddir.entrySet().iterator();
                while(itr2.hasNext())
                {
                    Entry entryset=(Entry) itr2.next();
                    Object key2=entryset.getKey();
                    Object value2=entryset.getValue();
                    if(value2.equals(value))
                    {
                        hex1=MD5Encryption.convertToHashCode(key2.toString());
                        //System.out.println(hex);
                        //System.out.println(hex1);
                        if(hex.toString().equals(hex1.toString()))
                        {
                            List<String> NoChangevalues=new ArrayList<String>();
                            NoChangevalues.add(key.toString());
                            NoChangevalues.add(key2.toString());
                            NoChange.put(value.toString(),NoChangevalues);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            List<String> Changevalues=new ArrayList<String>();
                            Changevalues.add(key.toString());
                            Changevalues.add(key2.toString());
                            change.put(value.toString(),Changevalues);

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            else
                newfile.put(key.toString(), value.toString());
        }

        Iterator itr2=filepath_seconddir.entrySet().iterator();
        while(itr2.hasNext())
        {
            Entry entryset=(Entry) itr2.next();
            Object key=entryset.getKey();
            Object value=entryset.getValue();
            if(!filepath_firstdir.containsValue(value))
                newfile.put(key.toString(), value.toString());
        }

        session.setAttribute("NoChange", NoChange);
        session.setAttribute("Change", change);
        session.setAttribute("newfile", newfile);

    return new ModelAndView("success","message",msg);
}


public Map<String, String> listFilesForFolder(File folder) {

    String temp="";
    Map<String,String> filepath=new HashMap<String,String>();
    //List<String> filepath2=new ArrayList<String>();
    for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
      if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {

        filepath.putAll(listFilesForFolder(fileEntry));
      } else {
        if (fileEntry.isFile()) {
          temp = fileEntry.getName();
          //if ((temp.substring(temp.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, temp.length()).toLowerCase()).equals("txt"))
          {
            System.out.println("File= " + folder.getAbsolutePath()+ "\\" + fileEntry.getName());

            filepath.put(folder.getAbsolutePath()+"\\"+fileEntry.getName(),fileEntry.getName());

          }
        }

      }
    }
    return filepath;
  }}
```

Comment: What about the commented code? Do we need it or can we delete it?

Comment: we can delete that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont pass the list of strings to jsp. Construct the tree on the serverside and send the tree there and render it. See this
[How to convert list of filepaths to a hireachial tree in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590694/how-to-convert-list-of-filepaths-to-a-hireachial-tree-in-java)