# If given a list of objects (files/folders) and their paths as a string, how do I organize them into a formal hierarchy?

Tags: java, hierarchical-data

I have a List of objects, which are either files or folders. They all contain a path as a string. How can I sort these into a hierarchy? If I have a folder objects that can hold folders and files and a regular file object, using a list of objects with their paths, how do I sort these into the folder and file objects?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try, provide some code of your own, and you will get help.

Comment: @Bentaye Sure, ill edit it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the composite pattern, you can easily represent that.

You could have as base class `Resource` and `File` and `Folder`, subclasses of `Resource`.
And the hierarchical notion would rely on `Folder` that composes a Set of `Resource` that can be so `File` and `Folder`.

String path and reference to the physical resource fields could be stored in `Resources` as these have the same representation in both subclasses.

To go further, as you represent data, generally you also want to manipulate them and preferably in a simple and uniform way.
For example as clients want to perform common operations on resource instances  (folder or a file) : creating, listing or deleting a resource, etc... it would be simpler for them if they can manipulate a single interface.
The composite pattern allows it.
Just declare in the base class (`Ressource`) the common operations and let subclasses to define the required behaviors.
That's all.

Comment: Right, thanks so much. I have already set up the resource class and two subclasses... you make an interesting point about the uniform actions of parents on children objects... thanks so much. I think I figured out an efficient way to sort them

Comment: You are welcome. So, you seem to be in the right way. Fine.

Comment: I have one more 'quick' question, I have found some serious flaws in my sorting algorithm. How would you go about sorting children into parents when there is a possibility of an infinite amount of parents? Nested folders withing nested folders, etc..... I seem to be having trouble getting past that first part.

Comment: Like that, I cannot really see your sorting algorithm issue. Is it not working ?
 Is it too slow ? Whatever the number of directory, the idea is to start from a directory and to iterate on each one of its direct children. And as this one is also a folder, iterate on each one of its direct children. If your issue is not solved, I think that it would be simpler if you opened a new question with this specific issue. I am sure someone will be able to help you. And if nobody, I could look at.

Comment: right so the issue is that the objects dont come with their children assigned to them, they all come separately. I found this question which is very close to mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005551/construct-a-tree-structure-from-list-of-string-paths